# Is it obvious that $\sum_n x_n = 0 $ when $x_n = 0 ~ \forall n \in \mathbb N$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, induction

Until recently I used to think that because of induction, a statement $P_n$ which is true $\forall n \in \mathbb N$ was also true when $n \to \infty$. Life was simple, and I was happy. Then someone (on this website) showed me a counterexample with $P_n = $ "$\sum_1^n$ is finite". I was shocked and confused.

My current understanding is that knowing that a statement is true $\forall n \in \mathbb N$ doesn't automatically imply that it is true when $n \to \infty$. The latter case might also be true, but needs a separate proof.

Now please help me understand the following two statements:

- if $x_n = 0 ~ \forall n \in \mathbb N$, then $\lim_n x_n = 0 $
- if $x_n = 0 ~ \forall n \in \mathbb N$, then $\sum_n x_n = 0 $

These two statements seem obvious but I don't trust "obvious" anymore. How do you prove them? What is the relationship between (1) and (2)?

Comment: In the first one it says $\{0, 0, \dots, 0\}$, the second one says $0 + 0 + \dots + 0 = 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using definition of limits:

Given any $\epsilon>0$ there DOES exist an $N (=1)$ for which $\forall n\geq N$ $$|x_n-0|=|0-0|=0<\epsilon$$
Thus, $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n$ does exist and is equal to $0$

You can do it similarly for the series. (The series DOES converge because the sequence of partial sums is exactly the sequence above)

Whenever you are in doubt of whether something "works". ALWAYS start with the definition. Theorems, propositions and corollaries are built on assumptions. Definitions are absolute.